# Unable to start python app using a startup script on GCP VM

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04

I am deploying a python app on the GCP instance group.

**The python version is 3.7**

I have a startup script in the instance's template, that starts the app using

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

This doesn't work for startups. I need to start the app, and it should keep running.
I have also tried

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Also , i tried

```
 nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

If , i SSH into the instance, all of the above commands work.
I tried using this bash script with name **revamp.sh**:

```
#! /bin/bash  
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The startup script in the meta data:

```
chmod +x revamp.sh
./revamp.sh
```

[image]

**The manage.py file and bash script are in the same directory.**

I checked the serial logs and it is showing this error:

[image]

But, I need the app to start from the startup script defined in the instance template. This way if instances scale, the app will start automatically.
The instance has Ubuntu 16

How can I achieve that?

Comment: 1) you must specify the full path to **manage.py** 2) Use the serial port to view messages regarding your script. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output

Comment: The script and the manage.py are in the same directory.

Comment: The fact that they are located together in the same directory does not mean the process current working directory is the same. Review the serial port output and update your question with details.

Comment: Update after your last edit. You cannot specify **./revamp.sh** and expect the system to know where **./** is located in the file system. When startup scripts run there is no **user** context. You are running as a privileged system process.

Comment: Yeah , i checked the serial port, and it is showing error. I have added the error in the post. 
How does it work, when I ssh into the machine and run the same script?

Comment: Which version of python is your program written for (2 or 3)? Edit your question and include your python program. If your script requires Python 3, use **python3 /path/to/manage.py**

Comment: Its for python3.7 , let me try with python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: The @JohnHanley remark about the user context is very important. you use `python3` because your `$PATH` env var contain the path in it, when you are in your user context when you are logged in SSH. But you can't assume that the `$PATH`env var is the same in the privileged user at startup script. Use full path for python binary also!! And with Ubuntu16, there is lot of chance that Python2 is the default version with you use `python` in a neutral context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you pull the manage.py from? Pass the python as in a shell script in the startup script metadata and try again:

```
#! /bin/bash
python /path/to/file/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: I tried using that. When the instance starts, the app is not running on the machine's external IP.
If I ssh into the machine and run the same bash script.It works

Comment: I have attached the bash script , and startup script in meta data in the post,

Comment: Ok so the app is not being executed at all? As John mentioned, try to debug if there is any error using the serial port to view the messages

Comment: Yeah , i checked the serial port, and it is showing error. I have added the error in the post. 
How does it work , when i ssh into the machine ,and run the same script?

Comment: What’s that syntax error about shown in the serial port?